# subprocess.call for sed inside python script with a variable passed to sed

Tags: python, sed, yaml, subprocess

I am in need to edit yaml file using a script for that I am trying to call a sed command inside python script using subprocess.call(), in that sed command i need to use a user input python variable

here ip is a variable , say for ex ip="check"
when I run the above script , instead of value for variable ip(that is "check" as per example) , I am getting >+ip being replaced
What should be written in the script in the place of >'+ip' , to get this done  ?

```
subprocess.call(["sed -i '0,/loadBalancerIP/! s/10..*$/>'+ip'/' sample.yaml"], shell=True)e here
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal reproducible example, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just pass the real value, not the variable.